# Export HTML to Excel using common function that displays on view page and exports data

Tags: php, excel

I have a function that fetches data from database and generates HTML in the `controller` function and I echo it and it gets displayed on the view file with ease. But, now I want to use this same function to export to `Excel`. I tried doing this but does not get exported. Logically it should happen. Following is code:

```
 public function export2($html)
    {
        $filename ="excelreport.xls";

        header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        echo $html;
    }
```

The `$html` contains the HTML table. the function `export2()` is called from within the function that fetches the data and creates HTML content.

Comment: That's because an Excel file is not simply an HTML file with an extension of xls - there are dozens of libraries that will help you write Excel files, but you have to read the documentation for those libraries

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly export data from html to excel.

You need to follow one of the below library to do that.

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data

Try sample code and let me know is you want any help.